# Parsing html with <br> tags (Python)

Tags: python, html, xpath, lxml

I'm using lxml to parse some html. HTML looks like:

```
<td valign="top">first text field<br>second text field</td>
```

And no, the break tag isn't closed anywhere down the line.

`element.text` returns the first of the two, and `element.xpath('string()')` returns both with no `\n` or other separator.

I figure I can just parse twice and "subtract" the former from the latter if I want only the second text field, but that's not ideal. I assume there must be some other way of getting that second text field but I'm stumped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answered myself. `element.xpath('text()')` returns an array of both things I'm looking for.

Comment: @felipsmartins not for another 2 days, according to SO